# Rebuilding sendmail on FreeBSD application server after adding new activedirectory domain controller to network

Tags: freebsd, dns, sendmail, domain

In the process of adding a new ActiveDirectory domain controller to our network, we decided to rename the domain from "domain.local" to "domain.priv." I scoured all parts of our application server for instances of "domain.local," replacing them with "domain.priv." I did change hostname and change the content of files in `/etc/mail` which had "domain.local" in them.

I also navigated to `/etc/mail` and rebuilt sendmail using `make`. New files with our new domain were generated, which was promising.

I then restarted sendmail and sent test emails, but none are being successfully sent.

Pertinent entry from `/var/log/maillog`:

`Authentication-Warning: server_name.domain.priv: deploy set sender to
user@company.com using -f`

Which other places on the server could contain the old domain name? What should I configure/reconfigure to ready this application server for the domain name change? At this point I'm not sure if it's sendmail, a DNS issue or simply the contents of some file on the application server

Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things were keeping mail from being sent out. The nameserver entry in `/etc/resolv.conf` was pointing to an IP address which no longer existed. I did not know this new domain controller/exchange server would have a new IP address. I changed an entry in `/etc/resolv.conf` to `nameserver 192.168.2.10` to `nameserver 192.168.2.11`.

`/etc/hosts` also contained an entry which had the old IP address. I changed this as well. Once both of these changes were made I restarted sendmail. After that, emails began to be successfully transmitted.

In troubleshooting this issue I found great value in using telnet, I'd never used it before. I highly recommend it.

Thank you for helping, @vonbrand. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

To change the sendmail configuration, you need to change the sendmail.mc file an rebuild the configurations. This stuff is nowadays in `/etc/mail`, and after editing `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`  you have to run `make` there (sorry, the setup can vary quite a bit, you'll have to dig into the documentation).

Comment: In `/etc/mail` I do not have `sendmail.mc` In fact, running `locate sendmail.mc` yielded no results.

Comment: In Fedora at least, you have to install a separate package that contains the configuration machinery for sendmail.